# Is "an ear that listens" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I read the following sentence:

> All he needs is a hug, a shoulder to cry on, a friendly touch, and ***an ear that listens***.

I think *the subject* of the verb *"listens"* should be somebody but not something. Is "an ear that listens" commonly used?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche

Comment: @snailboat I still can't search the information I want.

Comment: I think you want, "*All he needs is a hug, a shoulder to cry on, a friendly touch, and **a sympathetic ear***"

Comment: @Jim.we can't say"an ear that listens"??

Comment: @user48070- You can say it, but it is not idiomatic, and it is not symmetric with the rest of the items in the list either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [@snailboat](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/230/snailboat) pointed out, *ears that listen* is an example of synecdoche: a figure of speech in which a term for a part of something is used to refer to the whole of something, or vice versa. In this case, *ear* (a part of a person) is used instead of *person*; this usage is similar to saying *the law* instead of *the police*, or *the church* instead of  *the congregation*.

Yes, you can say *an ear that listens* or *a shoulder to cry on*; nobody will take it literally, and think you want to talk to an ear, or cry on a shoulder, detached from the rest of a body.

As for being commonly used, the *Corpus of Web-based Global English* finds three sentences containing *ear that listens*, and three sentences containing *ears that listen*. This doesn't mean the phrase would not be understood.

> We must be the extended hand that helps, **the ear that listens** and the compassionate heart that stands with them.

> We need to approach our children not as character projects, but rather, we must see them with hearts of sympathy, with compassion and understanding, and with **ears that listen**.

Comment: "(an) ear _to_ listen" is much, much more common, fwiw.

Comment: I think Jim has got it right in comments that *a sympathetic ear* is much more idiomatic and common. Beyond that this is a great answer though, +1.